# WPF DataGrid CanUserAddRows event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

Is there an event or command I could use so I can invoke the object that is getting added to the ObservableCollection before it gets added?

At the moment, once the user clicks the row in the grid, it adds it to the collection, however I need to specifically assign properties in C# that I don't want to assign in the grid.

```
public void event
{


// I want to do something before the CanUserAddRow event does this
collection.Add(<T>;

}
```

Comment: Please Describe it more.Do you want to add to the collection and do not show in the Data grid?

Comment: Hi harshana, not exactly, I have two properties that I was to assign myself (via c#) before the object gets added to the collection via the CanUserAddRow event does it.

So basically in english I want to say to the object "Wait, I want to change you before you getting to the collection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataGrid.InitializingNewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.initializingnewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
private void InitializingNewItem(object sender, InitializingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
    //use e.NewItem here
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> You can set default values for the new item by handling the InitializingNewItem event and setting the values programmatically

Comment: Perfect. Thanks (Will accept answer in a couple of mins)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure is that work for you...

```
private void DataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
  YourObject obj = e.Row.Item as YourObject;
  if (obj != null)
  {
     //see obj properties
  }
}
```

**Explanation :**

In here after user enter the data to the grid, and It takes as `e.Row.Item` Then you can change any of modification to your object.

Comment: I have done something like this but based on InitalizingNewItem event, so will mark it as useful + Thanks!